# outofmemoryexception while opening excel sheet using excellibrary in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, out-of-memory, import-from-excel

I am trying to open Excel sheet in my system using `excellibrary` for **C#**
but it's giving me an exception `outofmemoryexception`. Please help me fix this.
The line of code which I am using is:

```
 Workbook book=Workbook.Load("DailyReport.xls");
```

Excel sheet existing in the current path and file is of only 11 kb.